# keras load_model gives TypeError: int() argument 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, model

I am training successfully a neural network with keras and tensorflow on colab, like this:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

logpath_ms = './best_model.h5'
modelsave_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(logpath_ms, monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=30, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (n_input,X.shape[1]) ) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=(4), strides=4))
model.add(LSTM(units= 30 , return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units= 30 , return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units= 30))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['mse'])

model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, epochs=10, verbose=1,
             callbacks=[modelsave_cb])
```

As you see I save the model with callbacks when there is an improvement after an epoch. Unfortunately, when I try to load the model afterwards I get the error message:

```
model = load_model(logpath_ms)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ab300646bc5b> in <module>()
----> 1 model = load_model(logpath_ms)

28 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py in _compute_fans(shape)
   1423     fan_in = shape[-2] * receptive_field_size
   1424     fan_out = shape[-1] * receptive_field_size
-> 1425   return int(fan_in), int(fan_out)
   1426 
   1427 

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k6UCx46-M9oX7tLUbQvTFkt_hM3R1QAO?usp=sharing) to the colab notebook and here to the [h5-model file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1peM89qbajw_kchW_MctoTJFyBGCQVP13/view?usp=sharing). I thought the problem might be that the h5 file is empty (because of the error message 'NoneType'), but it's not. There is also not a typo in the file path, else I would get a different message. What's the reason for the error, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model was compiled in TF 1.x but you're executing it in 2.x. If you execute in 1.X, it works. You can put this in the first line in Colab to switch versions:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Do you know what should I change, so that the neural network would work and can save/load with TF 2.x?

Comment: Unfortunately, saved models are actually supposed to be compatible between versions but support is a bit [buggy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42106). However, this is the reason why (to my knowledge) there is no official weight converter between versions. You could try something like [this](https://github.com/OlofHarrysson/tensorflow-model-converter) though. The obvious other solution is to train the model yourself in 2.x if you have the resources for it.